# Getting the count for several document properties by grouping similar values

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to build a set of filters in a UI for an es object. I'd like to aggregate all the documents and group certain property's by value and get a count for each.

For example I'd like to be able to build a list of available filters like:

State :

- TX (5)
- NJ (1)
- CA (10)

Source :

- Location1 (30)
- Location2 (25)
- Location3 (22)

Where "State" and "Source" are different properties of the document type and the counts are in parenthesis obviously. I understand an Aggregation request would be what I want, I'm just looking for a little guidance. Ideally I'd like to do this with one request and not multiple requests for each property I need a group by count on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, If I am correct then, you just want count of 'state' for each state, and same case for source.

here is a request for that,

```
POST _/_search
{
    "size": 0,
    "aggs":{
        "state":{
            "terms":{
                "field" :"state"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Does that helps??